# How do i get other apps notification count?

Tags: javascript, android, notifications

In my custom launcher app I have a recyclerview of apps, and I am trying to implement unread notifications badge to every view.
How do I return the number of unread notifications for every app installed on my device?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669152/i-want-to-display-notification-count-badgeon-launcher-icon-in-android

Comment: That solution works for showing the badge on my app's icon.

Comment: Cool now please post the answer here as what you did to help others. Cheers